# PHP Updates to database not working

Tags: php, mysql, post

I am trying to create a login system that then shows all users information in a list, I have everything working so far except I can not have the 'rank' and 'role' update on the edit page working at the same time, e.g at the moment I have role working but rank does not update in the database, If i remove all of the code with role it will allow rank to update to the database again.

I was wondering if anyone could tell me why this is not updating to the database, it is currently updating the session info though.

```
    <?php 

    // First we execute our common code to connection to the database and start the session 
    require("common.php"); 

    // At the top of the page we check to see whether the user is logged in or not 
    if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) 
    { 
        // If they are not, we redirect them to the login page. 
        header("Location: login.php"); 

        // Remember that this die statement is absolutely critical.  Without it, 
        // people can view your members-only content without logging in. 
        die("Redirecting to login.php"); 
    } 

    // This if statement checks to determine whether the edit form has been submitted 
    // If it has, then the account updating code is run, otherwise the form is displayed 
    if(!empty($_POST)) 
    { 



        // If the user entered a new password, we need to hash it and generate a fresh salt 
        // for good measure. 
        if(!empty($_POST['password'])) 
        { 
            $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)); 
            $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt); 
            for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
            { 
                $password = hash('sha256', $password . $salt); 
            } 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            // If the user did not enter a new password we will not update their old one. 
            $password = null; 
            $salt = null; 
        } 


        // Initial query parameter values 
                $query_params = array( 
            ':rank' => $_POST['rank'], 
            ':user_id' => $_SESSION['user']['id']
        );
                        $query_params = array( 
            ':role' => $_POST['role'], 
            ':user_id' => $_SESSION['user']['id']
        );






        // If the user is changing their password, then we need parameter values 
        // for the new password hash and salt too. 
        if($password !== null) 
        { 
            $query_params[':password'] = $password; 
            $query_params[':salt'] = $salt; 
        } 

        // Note how this is only first half of the necessary update query.  We will dynamically 
        // construct the rest of it depending on whether or not the user is changing 
        // their password. 
        $query = " 
            UPDATE users 
            SET 
                rank = :rank
        ";
                $query = " 
            UPDATE users 
            SET 
                role = :role
        ";








        // If the user is changing their password, then we extend the SQL query 
        // to include the password and salt columns and parameter tokens too. 
        if($password !== null) 
        { 
            $query .= " 
                , password = :password 
                , salt = :salt 
            "; 
        } 

        // Finally we finish the update query by specifying that we only wish 
        // to update the one record with for the current user. 
        $query .= " 
            WHERE 
                id = :user_id 
        "; 

        try 
        { 
            // Execute the query 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
            // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        // Now that the user's rank has changed, the data stored in the $_SESSION 
        // array is stale; we need to update it so that it is accurate. 
        $_SESSION['user']['rank'] = $_POST['rank'];  



        // This redirects the user back to the members-only page after they register 
        header("Location: private.php"); 


        die("Redirecting to private.php"); 
    } 

?> 
<h1>Edit Account</h1> 
<form action="edit_account.php" method="post"> 
    battletag:<br /> 
    <b><?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['battletag'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></b> 
    <br /><br /> 
    Preferred Role:<br />
    <input type="radio" name="role" value="Assasin">Assasin 
    <input type="radio" name="role" value="Warrior">Warrior 
    <input type="radio" name="role" value="Specialist">Specialist
    <input type="radio" name="role" value="Support">Support
    <br /><br />
    Rank<br /> 
    <input type="text" name="rank" value="<?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['rank'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" /> 
    <br /><br /> 
    Password:<br /> 
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" /><br /> 
    <i>(leave blank if you do not want to change your password)</i> 
    <br /><br /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Update Account" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: Consider using [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) for your passwords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define `$query` twice, the second overwriting the first. You need to change it to

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET rank = :rank";
$query .= ", role = :role";
```

You may have had a conditional, but it is no longer present. Same is true for the `$query_params` definitions further up the script.